# Scripting with vim/sed to delete variable and replace it with several new lines above

Tags: vim, sed

I have this pattern in a file

```
~> more file.f
   c     %-------------------------------%
         integer*4 ierr, comm, myid, nprocs, cnprocs, color
         call MPI_INIT( ierr )
```

I need to delete `comm` and replace it with several lines at the top of it. For now, from a bash prompt (this will need to be scripted in a bash script in the end), I tried:

```
   vim -c "%g/      integer.\+comm/norm O" -c "x" file.f
   vim -c "%g/      integer.\+comm/norm k0s#ifdef HAVE_MPI_ICB\\r      type(MPI_Comm) comm\\r#else\\r          integer*4 comm\\r#endif\\r" -c "x" file.f
```

First `vim -c` is for creating a new line above. Second `vim -c` is for writting this new line using normal mode (would like to do this in one shot - didn't succeed for now!). I get (`+` sign below is output of `git-diff`)

```
  c     %-------------------------------%
 +#ifdef HAVE_MPI_ICB\r      type(MPI_Comm) comm\r#else\r      integer*4 comm\r#endif\r
        integer*4 ierr, comm, myid, nprocs, cnprocs, color
```

... Which is not what I need. Ideally, I need to get:

```
  c     %-------------------------------%
 +#ifdef HAVE_MPI_ICB
 +      type(MPI_Comm) comm
 +#else
 +      integer*4 comm
 +#endif
        integer*4 ierr, myid, nprocs, cnprocs, color
```

`comm` need to be deleted on the initial line and be replaced with the lines added above.

No clue how to get that. Can somebody help?

**EDIT**

I actually have 3 patterns to handle in the same file in different fortran subroutine (`comm` can come first or after the first variable)

```
  integer*4 ierr, comm, myid, nprocs, cnprocs, color
  integer*4         comm, myid, nprocs, rc, ierr
  integer*4         comm, nprocs, myid, ierr,
```

**EDIT**

Solution that works

```
sed -i.orig '/\(integer.*\)[[:blank:]]*comm, /{
s//\1/
i\
+#ifdef HAVE_MPI_ICB\
+      type(MPI_Comm) comm\
+#else\
+      integer*4 comm\
+#endif
}' file.f
```

Comment: Could you clean up the indenting of your code snippets? Your `file.f` doesn't have the 8 spaces indent that you put in your `:g` commands so it's all very confusing. Also, do you actually want those leading `+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `vi` scripting but a `sed` command would be:

```
sed -i.orig '/\(integer.*[[:blank:],]\)comm[[:blank:]]*,/{
s//\1/
i\
+#ifdef HAVE_MPI_ICB\
+      type(MPI_Comm) comm\
+#else\
+      integer*4 comm\
+#endif
}' file.f
```

Note: This won't work if the `comm` isn't followed by a `,` in the line.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work! Don't understand how the initial line get it's `comm` suppressed? Can you explain the details? Also, how to process the whole file (seems only first occurence is processed)?

Comment: @FGHP The `sed` command `/\(integer.*\),[[:blank:]]*comm/s//\1/` is equivalent to `vi` command `:%s/\(integer.*\),[[:blank:]]*comm/\1/`.  The ``i\`` command inserts the following line(s) (The slash at the end of the line denotes an embedded new-line character.). The `{` and `}` are for grouping commands. It should process all lines matching the regular expression `integer.*,[[:blank:]]*comm`, not just the first occurence.

Comment: OK, got it `/\(integer.*\),[[:blank:]]*comm/s//\1/` suppress `comm` by replacing it with the captured pattern: missed that. But I only get the first occurrence changed (I have 2 of them): is there a `g` missing in the sed command?

Comment: @FGHPF Could you show the unprocessed line that contain "integer" and "comm" ?

Comment: I added lines to process in the initial question

Comment: @FGHP Mea culpa. The regular expressed I've used was wrong. It is corrected now.

Comment: In the final regexp what does trigger  "add new lines" _above_? Not sure to understand this part of the regexp... How to say "add _below_" for instance (even if this may not be useful in this example)

Comment: @FGHPF That is not the part of regex. That is the ``i\`` (insert) command of `sed`. For "add below", you can use the ``a\`` (append) command.

Answer (score 0):

First store the new lines in a variable

```
read -d '' new <<@
+#ifdef HAVE_MPI_ICB
+      type(MPI_Comm) comm
+#else
+      integer*4 comm
+#endif
@
```

When you want to use `vim` commands, you might want to look at something like

```
ed -s file.f <<@ >/dev/null
/comm, /
s/comm, //
\$-1i
$new
.
w
q
@
```

However, nobody will understand what you are doing and it will only replace the first `comm,` .
With `awk`:

```
awk -v new="${new}" '/comm, / {print new} {gsub("comm, ",""); print}' file.f
```

The output will be written to stdout. Do not redirect to the input file (the input file will be made empty before `awk` starts reading) but redirect to a new file. When you want to edit `file.f` use something like

```
awk ... file.f > file.f.tmp && mv file.f.tmp file.f
```

Comment: More convenient to go with `sed` as I can do this in one shot!